# PHP user agent determining for both mobile and tablet

Tags: php, css, mobile, responsive-design, user-agent

i use this:

```
    $isMobile = (bool) strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'Mobile');

    if ($isMobile) {
        $Ymobile = "block";
    } else {
        $Ymobile = "none";
    }
```

This determines if the user is on mobile device, if yes it sets the class of a div to block.

However for a tablet, the div is shown.

So i changed the 'Mobile' to 'Tablet' and it worked, the div didnt show on the tablet.

How come the else doesnt hide the div on a tablet?

I thought i could do e.g.:

```
    $isMobile = (bool) strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'Mobile');
    $isTablet = (bool) strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'Tablet');

    if ($isMobile) {
        $Ymobile = "block";
    } else if ($isTablet) {
        $Ymobile = "none";
    } else {
        $Ymobile = "none";
    }
```

But that still shows the div.

Where am i going wrong?

Comment: What does `echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];` report when using a Tablet vs a Mobile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the link will help to detect Mobile or Tablet.

http://phpsnips.com/534/User-Agent---Mobile,-Tablet-or-not?-%28Works-with-Android,-iPhone,-Window-Phone-and-more%29#tab=snippet

http://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea..

Why don't you try a switch statement. If no 'Mobile' is detected then set none, in all other cases (is Mobile) then go for "block"

```
switch(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'Mobile')) {
    case false:
        $Ymobile = "none";
        break;
    default:
        $Ymobile = "block";
        break;
}
```

Comment: According to docs strpos returns false if the needle is not found so we could modify the code.

Comment: Much better. I'll remove my previous comment as it is no longer applicable.

Comment: The issue it appears is that 'mobile' counts as anything not a desktop. So upon checking and running some tests an ipad returns 'mobile' for the user agent. I just need to find what it should be for phones only. Shall researh

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using this:

https://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/wiki/Mobile_Detect

Very simple to use with tons of options.